# SQL : Command Create Virtual Row If Not Exist

Tags: php, mysql, sql

It is possible in MySQL to create new virtual row if the data doesn't exist, depending on user condition? 
My query looks like this:

```
 SELECT year, value, type FROM myTable 
 WHERE year BETWEEN ( '2010' AND '2013') AND type IN ('Oil', 'Gas');
```

Output:

```
   year | value | type
  ---------------------
   2013  |  0    | Oil
   2012  | 144.5 | Oil
   2012  | 434.3 | Gas
   2011  | 141.0 | Oil
   2011  | 1234  | Gas
   2010  | 4567  | Gas
  ---------------------
```

I want to run a query that will output records like this:

```
    year | value | type
  ---------------------
   2013  |  0    | Oil
   2013  |  0    | Gas  // -> new virtual* row
   2012  | 144.5 | Oil
   2012  | 434.3 | Gas
   2011  | 141.0 | Oil
   2011  | 1234  | Gas
   2010  | 4567  | Gas
   2010  | 0     | Oil // -> new  virtual* row
  ---------------------
```

The user want to display both 'Gas' and 'Oil', but since year 2013  only contain type 'Oil', so I want to create new record for 'Gas' with 0 value then same goes with year '2010' (based on the desired output above).

EDIT:

```
   CREATE TABLE `myTable` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `type` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,  
   `year` year(4) DEFAULT NULL,
   `value` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=92278 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: you can easily provide this view on client side(php), then why are you searching this type of query?

Comment: As type you only have oil and gas?

Comment: 'type' is dynamic also, it can contain anything like 'coal', 'power', etc. depends on user input. (actually, i have two tables for this, one for the values and the other for typeNames).

Comment: Can you please put the TABLE definition (DDL)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**As you mentioned you actually have 2 tables.**

I would prefer not polluting database with those 0 values, but if you insist.

```
INSERT INTO data
SELECT
  cross_join.year as year,
  0 as value,
  cross_join.id as type_id
FROM data
RIGHT JOIN (
  SELECT types.id, year
  FROM types
  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT year FROM data) distinct_years
) cross_join ON (cross_join.id = data.type_id AND cross_join.year = data.year)
WHERE data.year IS NULL
```

---

Another approach is to add those rows virtually during query, which I would prefer

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(data.year, cross_join.year) as year,
  COALESCE(data.value, 0) as value,
  COALESCE(data.type_id, cross_join.id) as type_id
FROM data
RIGHT JOIN (
  SELECT types.id, year
  FROM types
  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT year FROM data) distinct_years
) cross_join ON (cross_join.id = data.type_id AND cross_join.year = data.year);
```

[Demo can be found here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a8a09/12)

Comment: gracias! the second query is the one that im looking for, Sorry if i did not make it clear (on my quesion), I prefer virtual rows also. Cheers!